# npm run test - unsafe-perm in lifecycle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

I have a Reac/Redux app that runs fine, however when I run the following command

`npm run test`

I get the following error

```
6 info lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: MyApp@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: PATH: C:\....\...
9 verbose lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: CWD: C:\projects\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp-web
10 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'mocha --require src/testSetup.js "src/**/*.test.js*" ' ]
11 silly lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle MyApp@0.0.0~test: Failed to exec test script
13 verbose stack Error: MyApp@0.0.0 test: `mocha --require src/testSetup.js "src/**/*.test.js*" `
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\....\NodeJs\12.1.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\....\NodeJs\12.1.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
```

I don't know what is causing this issue. Any idea how I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this can help you, i found out my issue was the version of nodejs i was using.
I decided to install nvm(Node Version Manager) to "switch" versions and downgraded to the 11.13.0, and it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem

1:clear npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

2:Update Node.js

3:remove node_modules folder and run `npm i` again

4:probebly you have some error in terminal before show to you log file and require stack like this -> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

I install this package again

Answer (score 0):

I had to set nvm default to 14.
`nvm alias default 14.18`
I cant be certain when the issue started but I did install nvm recently.